# Why is forall true on an empty list?

Tags: scala

Why is this true?

```
List[Int]().forall(_ > 0)
```

My gut feeling was it should be false as no element can make the predicate true, but reality says otherwise and I don't understand why.

Comment: There are no elements for which the predicate does not hold. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202452/why-is-predicate-all-as-in-allset-true-if-the-set-is-empty .

Comment: "My gut feeling was it should be false as no element can make the predicate true" – Can you show me the element which violates the predicate? ;-)

Answer (score 5):

To add to the previous answers and comments: this is more consistent and leads to fewer surprises down the road.

For example, to check if a predicate holds for all elements of a big collection, you could employ a divide-and-conquer strategy: split the collection into smaller parts, run `forall` on each sub-collection, and combine the results with `&&`:

```scala
List(1, 2, 3, 4).forall(_ > 0)
// is equivalent to:
List(1, 2).forall(_ > 0) && List(3, 4).forall(_ > 0)
```

Now you could imagine "splitting" a collection into a collection containing exactly the same elements, and an empty one:

```scala
List(1, 2).forall(_ > 0)
// should be equivalent to:
List(1, 2).forall(_ > 0) && List[Int]().forall(_ > 0)
```

You wouldn't like the result of running `forall` on an empty collection to change the overall result, so it's convenient to treat it as `true`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a specific instance of a [*vacuous truth*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). The example given on Wikipedia is that the statement "all cellphones in the room are turned off" is *vacuously true* if there is no cellphone in the room. Interestingly, the statement "all cellphones in the room are turned on" is vacuously true, as is the statement "all cellphones in the room are turned off and turned on".

The basic intuition is that every element *which is there* satisfies the predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Logic dictates that an implication can only be false if the antecedent is satisfied, but the consequent isn't. That is, `P => Q` (`P` implies `Q`, or  "if `P` then `Q`") is false only if `P` but `!Q`. In any other cases, even in the case where `P` is false, `P => Q` is true.

And `forall` relies on an implication (i.e "if `x` satisfies `P`, include `x` in the resulting set"). If `forall` is applied to an empty set/list, no `x` will satisfy `P`

Answer (score 0):

This answer derives the fact from basically just two things:

- empty set is subset of the empty set
- definition of implication

Unlike all those handwavy [excluded-middle-answers in the linked MathOverflow answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202452/why-is-predicate-all-as-in-allset-true-if-the-set-is-empty), it doesn't even use negation anywhere.

---

Since `list.forall(p)` should behave the same as `list.toSet.forall(p)`, I'll speak only about sets.

Assuming that you accept the definition of "for all" in some more basic terms, you can prove that `Set.empty[A].forall(p)` must be `true`, regardless of what the condition `p` is.

One way to express such fundamental notions as "for all" in terms of something even more basic is given [in the last paragraph of this section on Lawvere Quantifiers](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quantification#lawvere_quantifiers_quantification_as_adjunction).

If one boils down the definition, it basically says:

- Given a set `X`
- and a predicate `p: X -> Boolean`
- consider the subset `S = { s in X | p(s) = true }` defined by the predicate
- and the preimage of the constant `true`-function:

  ```
  tPreimg(b: Boolean) = if b then X else emptySet
  ```

then `forall` is defined by the property

```
tPreimg(b) subset S  <=>  b implies X.forall(p)
```

Now, if one takes `X` as the empty set, then

- `tPreimg(b)` is always the empty set, regardless of the boolean value `b`
- `S`, as a subset of empty `X`, must also be the empty set
- Left hand side becomes `emptySet subset emptySet`, which is always true,
  because every set must be subset of itself.
- Thus, the right hand side must also be always true, regardless of the choice of Boolean `b`
- Thus, `X.forall(p)` must be true,
  because otherwise the right hand side would be false for `b = true`.

Hence, we obtain that for empty `X`, `X.forall(p)` must be `true`, regardless of how the predicate `p` is expressed.

Comment: I'm not sure that `tPreimg(b) subset S  <=>  b implies X.forall(p)` is good definition for `forall`. Because `forall(_)=true` fit that definition.

Comment: @talex For an empty `X`, `X.forall(p) = true` is the only choice that fits the definition, irrespective of `p`, that's what we wanted right from the beginning. It's maybe more interesting to consider a case where `X` is non-empty. Let's say `X = NaturalNumbersWithZero`. Then, of course, `forall` can no longer be constantly true, because, for example for the predicate `odd`, the `tPreim(true) = Nat` would not be subset of odd numbers, so the left hand side would be false, so the only choice for the `Nat.forall(odd)` would be false (because `true -> false` is the only way to make LHS=RHS=false).